# AWS lambda, C# async mail sending issue - MailJet API

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, .net-core, aws-lambda, mailjet

I was originally using AWS SES for mail sending from my Lambda, but it has very slow delivery.

I then decided to switch to MailJet and use their API for sending mails. I am using the NuGet package, V3.1 of the API, and pretty much the sample code from MailJet to send the mails async.

```
    public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(EmailModel model)
    {            
        Boolean sent = false;

        MailjetClient client = new MailjetClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EmailAPIKey"), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EmailAPISecret"))
        {
            Version = ApiVersion.V3_1,
        };

        MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest
        {
            Resource = Send.Resource,
        }.Property(Send.Messages, new JArray {
             new JObject {
                 {"From", new JObject {
                         {"Email", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SenderEmail")},
                         {"Name", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SenderEmailName")}
                     }
                 },
                 {"HTMLPart", model.EmailHtmlBody},
                 {"Subject", model.EmailSubject},
                 {"TextPart", model.EmailTextBody},
                 {"To", new JArray {
                     new JObject {
                         {"Email", model.EmailTo},
                         {"Name", model.EmailTo}
                     }
                 }}
             }
            });

        try
        {
            MailjetResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                sent = true;
                LambdaLogger.Log(string.Format("Total: {0}, Count: {1}\n", response.GetTotal(), response.GetCount()));
                LambdaLogger.Log(response.GetData().ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                sent = false;
                LambdaLogger.Log(string.Format("StatusCode: {0}\n", response.StatusCode));
                LambdaLogger.Log(string.Format("ErrorInfo: {0}\n", response.GetErrorInfo()));
                LambdaLogger.Log(response.GetData().ToString());
                LambdaLogger.Log(string.Format("ErrorMessage: {0}\n", response.GetErrorMessage()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception mailFail)
        {
            sent = false;
            LambdaLogger.Log(string.Format("Failed: {0}\n", mailFail.Message.ToString() + " : " + mailFail.InnerException.Message.ToString()));
        }
   
        return sent;
    }
```

When I test the code locally everything works just fine.

When I deploy the lambda to AWS and call the method for sending mails, it is completely random if the mail is send. I am guessing it is the async part which fails for some reason, I am hoping someone can help me to figure this out, because for now I am stuck on this issue.

Or if someone can tell me how to get Amazon SES to send without delay.

Comment: The second line of code looks like it has a syntax error?  Aside from that, what are the specifics of how this fails?  Don't "guess it is the async part", unless there's a specific observation to indicate that?  Is the response from MailJet successful but the email is just never received?  The code shown doesn't check the response like [the vendor's code](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-dotnet#make-your-first-call) does.  Perhaps there's an error you're just not observing?

Comment: I have now updated the code part to show the entire async method which works locally, but only sometimes when running in AWS. My best guess is I am doing something wrong with async / await, because it seems like the lambda just keeps running and does not wait for the reply from MailJet.

Comment: The `await` keyword is specifically for the purpose of waiting for the result of the operation.  (Though I certainly can make no guarantees about the 3rd party library being used or its reliability.)  How are you calling `SendEmailAsync`?  Are you awaiting its result?  Are you awaiting the result of the method which calls it?  Etc.  Basically, is the async/await structure maintained throughout the application?  The problem description so far implies that somewhere you may be invoking an async operation and then forgetting about it.

Comment: Your input was very helpful, it made me work my way back and you were right, there was a place where I did not have await. Now everything seems to be running smooth, even with Amazon SES. If you put your input as an answer I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question:

> it is completely random

And from a comment:

> it seems like the lambda just keeps running and does not wait for the reply from MailJet

It is sounding like an async/await issue, but probably not where you think.  Note that you are correctly awaiting the result of the MailJet operation:

```
MailjetResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);
```

But that's only in this method.  This method is of course `async`:

```
public async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(EmailModel model)
```

When you call *this* method, do you `await` it?  The method where you call it, that should also be `async`.  Do you await that?  Basically, are you ["async all the way down"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)?

It sounds like somewhere in the codebase there's an async operation that's being invoked and then forgotten.